# Xcode Moving from Storyboard

Tags: swift

I have a Xcode project using storyboards.

I have the typical setup,

- Segue in storyboard
- Call self.perform("..."....) from view controller
- This then calls 'prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)' allowing me to write variables in the new view controller before 'viewdidload' is called

Now the project is growing making using storyboards impractical.
We are taking a code approach loading views from code. The issue we are facing is how to pass data to new view before 'viewdidload' is called or what's the correct process to use.

We are loading view using

```
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "TestView", bundle: nil)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! TestViewController
    view.delegate = self
    view.dataModel = TestViewDataModel()
    present(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Issue we have is 'instantiate' calls viewdidload but ideally it needs data from 'datamodel'

Thanks

Comment: *"what's the correct approach"* - the one which works.  Ok, that's a little tongue in cheek, but at the end of the day you need to be able to develop a workflow which ultimately works for you.  Loading a view and loading a view controller (via code) have slightly different requirements in terms of workflow.  You should also consider trying to decouple the workflow, making use of `protocol`s to define the acceptable ways a caller may interact with the view/controllers in an independent way.  In the past I have use a factory style approach and a "logic" controller to manage the workflows

Comment: "We are taking a code approach loading views from code" Yes, but then I doubt that loading nibs is going to help any. I recommend creating / configuring views entirely in code and not using Interface Builder _at all_. Otherwise it is difficult to see what problem you think you are solving. After all, if the problem was merely that the storyboard was getting too big, you could have solved that by splitting it into multiple storyboards and jumping between them with storyboard references. So the problem must be that nibs themselves are bad.

Comment: To add to @matt comment, IB simply is a *design* way of doing what you can do in code. Think what a "segue" really is - and yes, that you *cannot* do in code as a "segue". Typically it's navigation, or working with a view controller stack. Now, a NIB? That's **not** a view controller - it simply a view. So if you/we are taking a code approach, think in these terms.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new initializer to `TestViewController` that takes accepts whatever data you need as parameters.

From within it, call `super.init(nibName: "TestView",  bundle: nil)`. `UIViewController`'s initializer will take care of finding the nib, instantiating itself from it, and settings itself as the owner.

```swift
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    let dataModel: TestViewDataModel

    init(dataModel: TestViewDataModel) {
        super.init(nibName: "TestView", bundle: nil)
        self.dataModel = dataModel
    }

    //...
}
```